# How to define a variable having value as octal 0 in javascript

Tags: javascript

how to define a variable having 0 as octal numbers in JS. 
`var x = 00;` will console log '0'. I am not sure If its octal/decimal.
anyone know ways to figure it out?

Comment: Just a question, what is the octal `0` to decimal `0`?

Comment: What do you mean 0 in octal numbers? `0` is octal `00` it's just as an integer type

Comment: JavaScript accepts octal numbers like `0o0`, but they just convert to base 10 Numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, a Number is a Number. They are not stored with any particular base.

A literal might be parsed as a decimal, octal or hexadecimal but will end up as a Number in the end.

Nothing is always nothing though. So `parseInt("0", 10)`, `parseInt("0", 16)`, and so on will give the same result as each other.

`0` is just zero.